GraphQL and Angular Docker compose
I have a backend with GraphQL and a frontend with Angular.
Both can work in Docker, but if I'm trying to docker-compose both I can access the frontend but the frontend did not get resposne from the backend.
Dockerfile Backend:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG configuration=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WeatherBackend.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "WeatherBackend.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WeatherBackend.csproj" -c $configuration -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG configuration=Release
RUN dotnet publish "WeatherBackend.csproj" -c $configuration -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WeatherBackend.dll"]

Dockerfile Frontend
FROM node:18 AS build
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install -g http-server

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8081"]

# # Build the Angular app for production
RUN npm run build --configuration=production

FROM nginx:latest

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /app/dist/weather-frontend/browser/ /usr/share/nginx/html

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  frontend:
    image: weather-frontend-image
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    environment:
      - BACKEND_URL=http://weather-test_backend_1:8080/graphql

  backend:
    image: weather-backend-image

After running docker-compose up -d I get the following
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS                                   NAMES
b256527de2bf   weather-frontend-image   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 days ago   Up 2 days   0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp, :::8081->80/tcp   weather-test_frontend_1
b720df4c5247   weather-backend-image    "dotnet WeatherBacke…"   2 days ago   Up 2 days                                           weather-test_backend_1

I can access the frontend but the frontend get CORS errors.
Backend Startup.cs
using HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Playground;

namespace WeatherBackend
{
        public class Startup
        {
                private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddHttpClient<WeatherService>();
            services.AddGraphQLServer()
                .AddQueryType<WeatherQueryType>()
                .AddApolloTracing()
                .AddType<WeatherType>()
                .ModifyRequestOptions(opt => opt.IncludeExceptionDetails = _env.IsDevelopment());
            services.AddCors(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
                    builder => {
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                               .AllowAnyHeader()
                               .AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });
            
            services.AddOptions();
            services.Configure<OpenWeatherMapOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ApiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OpenWeatherMapApiKey");;
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
            app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapGraphQL("/graphql");
            });
        }
    }
}

The backend already allows everything. Running this without docker everything is fine.
Please help and assist me to get this running.
As URL inside the frontend I used http://weather-test_backend_1:8080/graphql

Is the frontend running as a browser application?  If so, the browser may not be able to resolve the Docker-internal host names, and "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend might help you.  What is the exact error you're getting when you try to make the call?

Yes it is a browser application. The frontend is for showing weather data from openweathermap.org
The error is: for the OPTIOn request CORS failed and for the POST NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI
